# ARKit – Placing objects using latitude and longitude

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, core-location, arkit

I want to place an object in ARKit using latitude and longitude. Currently I can place the object using `SCNVector3 (x, y, z)`.

How can I place models using latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely place models using latitude and longitude with [ARGeoAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeoanchor):

```
ARGeoAnchor(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, altitude: CLLocationDistance?)
```

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884844/adding-3d-object-to-argeoanchor/65200766#65200766) telling about `ARGeoTrackingConfig`'s implementation.

Comment: @SimranRout, pay particular attention, at the moment ARGeoTracking works only in US cities. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeotrackingconfiguration