# Getting errors when running AR App template in Xcode

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, beta, realitykit

Running Xcode 13 beta on MacOS 12 beta deploying to iPad Pro 4th gen running iOS 15 beta.

In Xcode, I create an app using the Augmented Reality App, selecting default SwiftUI interface, Swift language, and RealityKit content technology.

Once created, I make absolutely no changes to the code, and simply run it on my iPad. I get many deprecation and types don't exist errors/messages, in addition to others - displayed below.

I'm somewhat new to the Apple dev environment so maybe I'm missing something very basic, but why would I get so many warnings/errors on template code? Is this typical with Apple beta product?

```
2021-06-15 09:37:13.272034-0700 Test[47081:3536556] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2021-06-15 09:37:13.272264-0700 Test[47081:3536556] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-06-15 09:37:15.828657-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [AssetTypes] Registering library (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRE.framework/default.metallib) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.003778-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/suFeatheringCreateMergedOcclusionMask.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.040593-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arKitPassthrough.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.041875-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/drPostAndComposition.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.042944-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arSegmentationComposite.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.044096-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute0.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.045368-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute1.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.045793-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute2.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.055039-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute3.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.055471-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute4.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.055856-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute5.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.056249-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute6.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.056638-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Assets] Resolving material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/arInPlacePostProcessCombinedPermute7.rematerial' as an asset path -- this usage is deprecated; instead provide a valid bundle
2021-06-15 09:37:16.057596-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Foundation.Serialization] Json Parse Error line 18: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableARProbes' - skipping.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.057645-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [Foundation.Serialization] Json Parse Error line 20: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableGuidedFilterOcclusion' - skipping.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141075-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "SceneComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141118-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "AcousticMeshComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141298-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "MainAudioMixerComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141418-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "LegacyCameraComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141482-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "CharacterControllerComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141522-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "CharacterControllerStateComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141553-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "ClippingBoxComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141581-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "ClippingPrimitiveComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141680-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "EventDelegateComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141739-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141772-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "KeyValueComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141867-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "FrustumLightComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141911-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "FilterMapComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141943-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VFXSceneComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.141972-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "RenderGraphFileProviderArrayComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142080-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "MeshSceneComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142107-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "MeshSortingComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142153-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "HierarchicalFadeComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142319-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "PlanarReflectionCaptureComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142349-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "PlanarReflectionReceiverComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142578-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "PhysicsDebugComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142649-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "StateMachineComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142771-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VideoPlaybackComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142809-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "SceneUnderstandingRootComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142845-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "SceneUnderstandingRenderOptionsComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142909-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "PinComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142939-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "PhysicsConstraintsComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.142970-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VertexCacheComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143002-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VisualProxyCaptureComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143032-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VisualProxyScopeComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143067-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "VisualProxyComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143099-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "ThrottleComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143140-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "TimebaseComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143169-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "NetworkAssetComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143203-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "DeferredActivationComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143229-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "LatencyEventsComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143253-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "RenderCallbacksComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143281-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "TintComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.143310-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "ProbeClusterExclusionComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.195752-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [UIFocus] Focus system enabled
2021-06-15 09:37:16.200618-0700 Test[47081:3536556] [ECS.Components] Type "CustomComponentRFAnchorDefinitionComponent" does not exist in previous RealityKit version.
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389036-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389596-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389654-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389704-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389756-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389831-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389883-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389937-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:16.389992-0700 Test[47081:3536556] throwing -10878
2021-06-15 09:37:17.371869-0700 Test[47081:3536950] [Technique] ARWorldTrackingTechnique <0x1158564c0>: World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should ignore those warnings because you're using betas (Xcode 13 and macOS).

However, it'll not be superfluous to check whether your geo location is [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884844/adding-3d-object-to-argeoanchor/65200766#65200766) in AR geo tracking config or not. And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800039/realitykit-adding-modelentity-to-an-argeoanchor/71801799#71801799) can also shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, Andy - I thought it to be a beta issue, but I guess the question is really: does it matter to the program function? I'm having problems with geoAnchors (basically, they're not showing up) and I'm trying to figure out if these warnings/errors are somehow interfering. If I know I can ignore these, I can continue on figuring out what I'm doing wrong elsewhere and not have these nagging at me as to whether or not they're interfering somehow.

Comment: What's your current location?

Comment: I'm in downtown Seattle, about 2 blocks from Pike Place Market - I know I have location services here (plus i check for device support and location services in the code). I'm doing something else wrong, i'm sure, but I think I'll figure that out. Just want to be able to exclude these initial template warnings as nothing I need to worry about.

Comment: Yes, I do check for geolocation - I check precisely as per the sample app from WWDC. I'm just going to assume that I can safely ignore those warnings that come when using the template, and get on with debugging my issues. Thanks, Andy!

Comment: Thanks, Andy! Can you please add that 'ignore' to your answer so i can mark it as the answer?