# Test Geospatial Anchor app for development and debbugging purpose

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, remote-debugging, arcore, ar-foundation

I'm building an AR App with AR Core and AR Foundation with Unity that instatiate an object to a specific latitude and longitude with Geospatial Anchor API.

I have to test if that work all correctly but the coordinates are far from me, and I can't always be physically on the spot.

I'm doing some test in a place near to me but I want start to build the real app.

There are some method to debug this type of application withouth be without being physically present on site?

Comment: Mattia, the answer to your question is here – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72557209/using-geospatial-api-without-google-street-view/72568839#72568839